# Is there any way to make vertical lines in a table, with JavaScript, HTML or CSS, if the table is missing some of the TDs?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, caa

Basically, I would like vertical lines to go all the way to the top of my table, even if there is not a td in the top top of the table.

I am open to using divs or seomthing like that is if it is not too complex.

EDIT:  I guess what I want are column dividers, even if there is not tds in that particular row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .sample td{border-left: 1px solid red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing='0' class='sample'>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td><td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, by 'vertical lines' you mean cell borders? BTW, there can't be more cells in a row than in another, use colspan if you want to fill extra space avoiding writing empty <td></td>

Comment: I mean any sort of vertical lines.

Comment: I do not want the tds to get wider.  If I used colspan, it will make the tds wider.

Comment: Where do these vertical lines come from?? anyway, I believe you should write an equal number of <td>s if you don't want to use colspan

Comment: How do you know which cell is missing? Taking the first row, there are 3 cells missing, which ones? 1,2,3 or 3,4,5 or whatever? Where does the table came from?

Comment: What I can't do it make the vertical lines. I am producing this HTML on the on fly. I would like to do it in one pass. I don't know ahead of time how many td the longest row will have.

Comment: If I write the extra TDs in, that will require a second pass through the data to add the correct number of TDs.  One pass to count the max length, and then a second pass to make all the columns that length.

Comment: I guess I am hoping for a way to avoid haivng to do the second pass.

Comment: ? Can you show the code that prints this way?

Comment: @Dr. Molle  The missing columns are always at the end.

Comment: If you want to avoid the 2nd pass you  should show us the first one :)

Comment: The first pass just splits up each row, by a delimiter and produces tds.

Comment: However, I don't know how many occurrences of the delimiter there is.

Comment: [bad solution] use a background image of a grid the size of your table cells, which repeats along the x axis so to fill the space where there are missing <td>s while giving the impression of there being a cell.

Comment: I know know the table cell size ahead of time.

Comment: If its not possible it's not possible.

Comment: This really is not a CSS problem I guess.  I guess have to change the data, like you mentioned below.

Comment: If you would provide HOW you fetch these datas, then we can help you better in solving this problem! Post the code that gives you this set of datas, and let's see what can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite like this, is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<body>
            <table cellspacing='0' class='sample'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
```